# URL opens in browser but not in android program

Tags: android, httpclient

There is a URL which opens fine on PC and mobile browser (chrome), but when i try to open it in an android program using below code it gives following error.

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
  String response = "";
  for (String url : urls) {
    //DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
   // httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Chrome");
    try {
      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
      InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
      String s = "";
      while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
        response += s;
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  return response;
}
```

on running the code I get an Access Denied error from the server. If I try any other url it works fine. I have tried searching on how to set user-agent to bypass any restrictions put on the server, but could not succeed. Please help.

Additionally I have seen that the header section of the webpage from which this url is called (from browser) contains the below

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
 <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
 <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: have you given internet permission in manifest ??

Comment: yes, other url's are opening fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a php file as below

```
<?php
$headers = apache_request_headers();

foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
echo "$header: $value <br />\n";
}
?>
```

I called this page from the PC browser and from within Android code. Added all the header values that came from the PC browser in the Android code using httpGet.setHeader(name,value)

It's working now. :)

Comment: It worked when added httpGet.setHeader(name,value) on app side, Otherwise causing "mod security action error : 403" when requested through app.